# PLAIN authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: Begin TLS negotiation now)]

Tags: php, sendgrid

Recently our code which has been working for the last 10 years has been throwing the error below:

> PLAIN authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220,
> response: Begin TLS negotiation now)]

This will be resolved when in the authentication we TURN OFF peer authentication.

'auth' => "PLAIN",

'socket_options' => array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false))

Has something changed at SendGrid?

Comment: Update your root certificates and turn on verifying full ssl.

Comment: Main question is how often did you update the system within the last 10 years? They probably turned off outdated TLS versions and/or updated their root certificate. But never do `'verify_peer_name' => false`.